# Whether javascript allow convert an existed variable to be a constant variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a special case to use javascript. There is a variable defined by `var myVar=xxx`. Then I want to protect this variable to be changed by other code. I know that I can define the variable with `const` at beginning but there is some reason I can't do that. So I am looking for a way to convert an existed variable to be a const variable. Not sure whether it is possible.

Comment: You cannot. ........

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change your `var` into a `const`, but assuming that `myVar` is defined on the global object you can make the binding final using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```js
var myVar = 'sacred-value'

Object.defineProperty(window, 'myVar', {
  writable: false,
  value: window.myVar
})

myVar = 'evil-value'

console.log(myVar) //=> 'sacred-value'
```

**Note:** I have assumed the `window` object is your global context here, but if you are executing in a non-browser environment you may need to use `global` instead.

Comment: No, `var`-declared global properties are already nonconfigurable

Comment: (…unless they were created by `eval`)

Comment: Could you explain to me what incorrect assumptions I made in more detail? I am having trouble seeing why my snippet appears to be working correctly given your criticism.

Comment: Sorry, again I was thrown off by the fact that [even nonconfigurable properties can be reconfigured to be nonwritable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9843191/1048572). Everything's fine, this is a good solution for global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a `var` into a `const`.

You could store your variable in an object, mutate it, and then freeze the object with [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to prevent further mutations:

```js
const variables = {
  a: 'b'
};

variables.a = 'c';
Object.freeze(variables);
variables.a = 'd'; // does nothing
console.log(variables.a);
```

Comment: I tried to freeze the variable directly but it doesn't help. Is Object.freeze not working for a single variable?

Comment: `Object.freeze` makes objects immutable. It doesn't affect variable binding, so it won't work for your use-case without storing your variable in an object.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the type of a variable declaration afterwards. However, you can introduce a new scope where you declare it as a constant:

```
var myVar = "xxx"; // assuming global scope

{
    const myVar = window.myVar; // or `this.` or `global.` depending on your environment
    … // your code here that will throw on assigning to `myVar`
}
```